# Simulating AR(1) process

Tags: r, time-series

Suppose I want to simulate an AR(1) process, following from this example given by W. Wei Time Series Analysis Univariate and Multivariate Methods.

[image]

I have attempted this by the following:

```
arima.sim(list(c(1,0,0), ar=-.65), n=250)
```

However, how do I take into account the gaussian white noise?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rand.gen argument that allow you to generate random innovations :

```
arima.sim(n = 63, list(ar = c(0.8897, -0.4858), ma = c(-0.2279, 0.2488)),
          rand.gen = function(n, ...) sqrt(0.1796) * rt(n, df = 5))
```